# Where does Python gets its traceback information from?

Tags: python, c, debugging, python-c-api

Consider the following `verysimple.py`:

```
if '__main__' == __name__:
    prnt('Line1')
```

Now, if I execute it with `> python verysimple.py`, I am, of course, greeted by:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "verysimple.py", line 2, in <module>
          prnt('Line1')
    NameError: name 'prnt' is not defined`
```

I'd like to know where in the [python-c-api](/questions/tagged/python-c-api) Python is pulling the traceback information from (especially the erroneous command).

I've already tried to find my way inside `PyEval_FrameEx`, but can't figure it out...

Comment: @Dayalrai rai because I'm looking for the C routine that does it...

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do wnat to know?

Comment: @Evert I'd like to learn about the way Python is retrieving line number, source code from the opcode.

Comment: @SebGR I think that actually happens well before that, when Python parses the code and converts it into its syntax tree, storing the line numbers along the way. It's only when Python starts to evaluate the code that it raises an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. When parsing the code tree, it just runs through `PyEval_FrameEx` multiple times.
In the end, it will call `format_exc_check_arg()` to format the error, which for me happens at line 2100 in the `ceval.c` of the Python version 3.3.2 source.
`format_exc_check_arg()` deduces the offensive 'object' (`prnt`) and calls `PyErr_Format` in `errors.c` to properly format the exception string (the exception type and its corresponding string, `NAME_ERROR_MSG`, were already passed to `format_exc_check_arg()` from this line 2100.

I used simply this code for testing:

```
prnt('Line1')
```

and then run it through a [debug build](http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#compiling-for-debugging) of Python 3.3 I had around.

The surrounding code in `PyEval_FrameEx` is

```
    TARGET(LOAD_NAME)
        w = GETITEM(names, oparg);
        if ((v = f->f_locals) == NULL) {
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_SystemError,
                         "no locals when loading %R", w);
            why = WHY_EXCEPTION;
            break;
        }
        if (PyDict_CheckExact(v)) {
            x = PyDict_GetItem(v, w);
            Py_XINCREF(x);
        }
        else {
            x = PyObject_GetItem(v, w);
            if (x == NULL && PyErr_Occurred()) {
                if (!PyErr_ExceptionMatches(
                                PyExc_KeyError))
                    break;
                PyErr_Clear();
            }
        }
        if (x == NULL) {
            x = PyDict_GetItem(f->f_globals, w);
            Py_XINCREF(x);
            if (x == NULL) {
                if (PyDict_CheckExact(f->f_builtins)) {
                    x = PyDict_GetItem(f->f_builtins, w);
                    if (x == NULL) {
// below is the line where the PyExc_NameError will be properly formatted.
                        format_exc_check_arg(
                                    PyExc_NameError,
                                    NAME_ERROR_MSG, w);
                        break;
                    }
                    Py_INCREF(x);
                }
                else {
                    x = PyObject_GetItem(f->f_builtins, w);
                    if (x == NULL) {
                        if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_KeyError))
                            format_exc_check_arg(
                                        PyExc_NameError,
                                        NAME_ERROR_MSG, w);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        PUSH(x);
        DISPATCH();
```

Note that two lines above it, `PyDict_GetItem(...)` will be the line trying to find `prnt` inside the builtin statements & functions (I deduce that from `f->builtins`, to which `w` is applied, `w` itself gotten from the second statement in the above code.
Since that dictionary lookup will fail, `x == NULL` and the `NameError` is set and formatted.

Hope this helps you further.